# Use multiple selected items from listbox in WhereClause for ArcGis

Tags: vb.net, listbox, arcgis

I am able to select a single selected item in ArcGis using WhereClause. Currently I am working on the selection of multiple items and writing a WhereClause with these selected items.

My question is: how do I build a WhereClause with multiple items. Or; how do I populate a msgbox with multiple selected items? The multipleclause is the variable which I want to loop untill all items are used.

```
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    count = ListBox3.SelectedItems.Count
    If count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Geen features geselecteerd")

    ElseIf count = 1 Then
        result = veld & "= '" & waarde & "'"
        MsgBox(result)

    Else
        firstclause = veld & "= '" & waarde & "'"
        For Each waarde In ListBox3.SelectedItems
            Do Until waarde Is Nothing
                multipleclause = " OR " & veld & "= '" & waarde & "'"
            Loop
        Next

        result = firstclause & multipleclause
        MsgBox(result)

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started

```
Dim count As Integer = 0
count = ListBox3.SelectedItems.Count
If count = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Geen features geselecteerd")

ElseIf count = 1 Then
    result = veld & "= '" & waarde & "'"
    MsgBox(result)

Else
    Dim sb as new System.Text.StringBuilder
    dim bFirst as Boolean = True
    For Each waarde In ListBox3.SelectedItems
        if bFirst Then
            bFirst = False
        else
            sb.append(" OR ")
        End If
        sb.Append(veld & "= '" & waarde & "'")
    Next

    result = sb.tostring
    MsgBox(result)

End If
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code works. Do you have a link which explains the code you've used?

Comment: The only thing really different than what you did is I used a String Builder (optional) which is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx  The only reason I use it is because it is much faster for concatenating strings than `a = a & b` or `a &= b`